# POST request returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs, body-parser

When the request from postman initiated with the json as given below, I get `hello undefined` as response.

request json

```
{
"name":"test"
}
```

my middleware

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/hello', (req, res)=>{
  return res.send("hello");
});

app.post('/hello', (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  return res.send(`hello ${req.body.name}`);
})

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('listening on port 8000'));
```

started the server with following command

```
npx babel-node src/server.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since express 4.16.0 you can use app.use(express.json()); to get the json data from request,in your case it would be.You don't require to use bodyparser and all.

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // remove this
app.use(express.json())// add this line
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, actually it returns same response. :(

Comment: what does `console.log(req.body )` returns?

Comment: it returns an empty object.  `{}` is printed to console.

Answer (score 2):

Actually issue is not with the code. The Postman client making the request didn't mark it as `application/json` type request. Once I rectified it, it just worked as expected.

Comment: But avoid using body parser use express json

Answer (score 0):

use bodyParser as meddleware

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //add this
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

also

```
app.post('/hello', (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  name.push(req.body.name) // add this if you store in array 

  return res.send(`hello ${req.body.name}`);
})
```